# didSet goes in an infinite loop in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift5

I just drag & drop `UISlider` in my `UIViewController` from `UIStoryboard` and want to do some transform. So, I write the code under `didSet` method and it goes under infinite loop. What I am doing wrong?

```
@IBOutlet weak var sliderNew: UISlider! {
    didSet {
       // Below code calling infinite times
        let scale = self.view.frame.size.width * 0.25
        sliderNew.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2).scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
    }
}
```

> Update

In case, if I just write the below code then it works fine.

```
@IBOutlet weak var sliderNew: UISlider! {
    didSet {
        sliderNew.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2).scaledBy(x: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    }
}
```

I tried with the another way but still the same issue.

```
@IBOutlet weak var sliderNew: UISlider! {
    didSet {
        sliderNew.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2).scaledBy(x: sliderScale, y: sliderScale)
    }
}

fileprivate var sliderScale: CGFloat {
    //The below code calling infinite loop, why?
    return self.view.frame.size.width * 0.25
}
```

Comment: This is caused because you try to access `self.view` (which is not loaded at that time) which in turn tries to load the view (and I'm assuming trying to set the outlet again (?)). In any case, you should do any transformations _after_ the layout is calculated since you rely on view's frame (maybe in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`).

Comment: @Alladinian I think `didSet` is called once the view is loaded that's why I wrote in that! Because the view is loaded then only we can do any changes, right?

Comment: I don't think that the view is loaded at that point (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197785/when-how-outlet-didset)). Again, if you need to refer to the view's frame, you must do so after the layout is finished.

Comment: Okay that can be the case, but it's strange!